# (MacOS Mojave 10.14.6) - Why 'lib' inside /usr/local is a Unix Executable file and not anymore a folder?

Tags: macos-mojave, dylib, lib

I have a very fresh and clean install of Mojave 10.14.6 on my 'Late 2013 MacBook Pro' (I haven't just updated from High Sierra 10.13), and I noticed that where there used to be the folder 'lib' inside path /usr/local now there is a Unix Executable file, also named 'lib', of about 7.6MB.

[current situation in Mojave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGLfB.jpg)

Now, for a project requirement, I'd need to copy 3 dynamic libraries inside /usr/local/lib/ folder, but obviously I'm prevented from creating a folder with the same name of the Executable. I tried to look for a solution or any insight into this question, although it looks like no one really experienced this problem.

Does anyone know why there has been such change, or if this is only my odd problem?
Is there any workaround so that I can add *.dylib files to path: /usr/local/lib/ if I can't create a folder with that same name?

I would really appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something has gone quite wrong... could you add the output of running `xxd -l 0x200 /usr/local/lib` to your post so that we can get an idea what the file actually contains? Is it an actual, functional executable, or just some garbage with the --x bit set?

Comment: Thank you so much @Siguza! your comment and xxd command helped me a lot to understand what actually happened..
Looking at a bit more than 32 lines of hexdump, the executable seemed being part of a specific dylib I was working with, and its size confirmed it was the same file as ‘that’ dylib.
The full story is.. I also found the shell script that tried to copy ‘that’ dylib inside /usr/local/lib without checking first whether such path existed.
In fact, lib folder didn’t exist and ‘that’ dylib ended up being an executable named just like the folder it should have been inside..
Thanks again!